# Is there a way to retain value of a variable even if localStorage is cleared

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 14 and currently there is no `ngrx` state management in the application. I need to retain the value of a variable even if the user refreshes the page. I've two components. In first component I'm setting some value in localStorage and in the second component I'm simply getting that value:

**component-1**

```
ngOnInit() {
    localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'Apple')
}
```

And in the second component I'm simply reading the value and after that I also need to clear the localStorage:

**component-2**

```
myFruit: string='';

ngOnInit() {
    this.myFruit = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
    ...
    ...
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log(this.myFruit); // OUTPUT: ERROR TypeError: this.myFruit is null
}
```

I have to clear the localStorage. That's why I'm setting the value before clearing it. Please correct my mistake. I need to retain the value of `myFruit` even if the user refreshes the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using session storage - I am unclear why you **have** to clear local storage, but if you're not going to pass this data to a database, and you don't have access to your browser persistent storage, then there is no possible way

Comment: I was looking for a temporary solution. For now I'll use `sessionStorage`. But very soon I'll be moving to state management using `ngrx`.